# High CPU load on SYN flood

Tags: security, linux-kernel, spoofing, denial-of-service, sysctl

When being under SYN flood attack, my CPU reach to 100% in no time by the kernel proccess named `ksoftirqd`,
I tried so many mitigations but none solve the problem.

This is my sysctl configurations returned by the `sysctl -p`:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0
fs.file-max = 10000000
fs.nr_open = 10000000
net.core.somaxconn = 128
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 2500
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 10
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 300
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 262144
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 2048
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 262144
net.ipv4.tcp_reordering = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 10485760
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 15
vm.swappiness = 10
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 1
```

Even after activating the Syn cookies, the CPU stays the same,
The Listen queue of port 443 (the port under attack) is showing 512 SYN_RECV, which is the default backlog limit set by the NGINX.

Which is also wired because the `SOMAXCONN` is set to a much lower value than 512 (128), so how does it exceed that limit?
`SOMAXCONN` needs to be the upper boundary for every socket listen and its not..

I read so much and I'm confused,
As far as I understood the `SOMAXCONN` is the backlog size for both LISTEN and ACCECPT queues,
so what exactly is the `tcp_max_syn_backlog`?
And how do I calculate each queue size?

I also read that SYN cookies does not activate immediately, but only after reaching the `tcp_max_syn_backlog` size, is that true?
And if so, it means its value needs to be lower than the `SOMAXCONN`..

I tried even activating `tcp_abort_on_overflow` when being under attack but nothing changed,
if its true that the SYN coockies is activate on overflow, applying them togerther result what?

I have ubuntu 18, 2 cores with 3 gigs of ram that uses only 700MB, even under attack, my only problem is the CPU load.
I'm willing to add resources if thats the problem, but after adding 8 more cores the result was 100% usage on each, so it's seems not to be the issue

Comment: Is there any chance you're really more interrupt-bound due to a high rate of packet reception interrupts from the NIC? Does your NIC support interrupt coalescing? Is it enabled?

Comment: Are you using LOG target in iptables? Try switch to NFLOG and see.

Comment: @Spiff I'd rather not to enable this, if only I could enable it on new connections and not established ones so I might have considored it.
I'v seen the log, I used `netstart` and counted the `SYN_RECV` that showed 512, and kernel logs too.
I just want to avoid the denial of service..