# How to allow only 100 half open SYN connections

Tags: linux, iptables, tcp, denial-of-service, sysctl

I'm running Ubuntu and want to allow only 100 waiting SYN connections at a given time,
and drop the rest.

How can I configure `iptables` to implement this rule?

Or `sysctl` config to allow only 100, and drop the others

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? What build of Ubuntu?

Comment: sysctl: https://superuser.com/questions/1635367/high-cpu-load-on-syn-flood
ubuntu server 18

Comment: Is this basically a repeat of your previous, unanswered question?

Comment: @Scott it doesnt have to be iptables, in fact it better not be.
I'd rather it'll be kernel (`sysctl`) solution, by allowing only and not by blocking,
but i'll be greatful for an `iptables` rule as well

Comment: @music2myear not exactly, but now I'm asking how to internally allow 100 half open connections, or what is the rule need to block this traffic?

Comment: @iTaMaR, Why 100?  What is your underlying goal?  How did you determine that 1) you'll be fine with 100, and 2) you won't be fine with 101?  How do you count syn cookie connections (are they half-open, or does the fact that the kernel isn't maintaining state mean they don't count?)?  Is this 100 per open port, or 100 total for the interface?  For the host?

Comment: @Slartibartfast I want the total `SYN_RECV` connection state of `eth0` (with any open ports) to count no more than 100.
Syn cookies are not considered open connections, I'd like to abort the overflow (100+) connections or pass them to the syn cookies mechanism..
I care the most about preformance and wish to try to abort them completely first that might save some more CPU than the rest of the other methods, and I'd like to test the `iptables` rule preformance against the abort by kernel